# Spaces are missed in the resulting bibliography in the epub when running tex4ebook

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht, tex4ebook

When running `tex4ebook' with the following MWE, there should be a` space separation` between the bibitems viewed in the epub to get a better result.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{westfahl:space}
\nocite{set}
\nocite{stdmodel}
\nocite{aksin}
\nocite{bertram}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\nolinkurl#1{#1}
\Css{dd.thebibliography { text-indent: -2em; margin-left: 2em;}}
\Css{dt.thebibliography + dd.thebibliography{margin-top: 1em;}}
\Css{dd.thebibliography p:first-child{ text-indent: -2em; }}
\Css{dt.thebibliography{float:left; clear:left; margin-right:1em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, Michal, that is a nice setting of the bibliography in the epub, much more readable and logically structured. Thank you so much.